# EC2 SSH sudden keypair issue

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I was normally working with the SSH on my server, then disconnected to re-connect using a different keypair, but received this message:

> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @
>   WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
>   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ IT IS
>   POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
>   Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)! It is also
>   possible that a host key has just been changed. The fingerprint for
>   the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
>   SHA256:****. 
>   Please contact your system administrator. Add correct host key in
>   /home/**/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message. Offending ECDSA
>   key in /home/**/.ssh/known_hosts:4   remove with:   ssh-keygen -f
>   "/home/**/.ssh/known_hosts" -R
>   ec2-**.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com ECDSA host key for
>   ec2-**.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com has changed and you
>   have requested strict checking. Host key verification failed.

I insisted and didn't work. Deleted the known host and didn't work.

Now the old keypair doesnt work either if i try to connect to ubuntu@ec2-**.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com. The new error is

> Permission denied (publickey).

The only way to connect is directly using the public IP. I tried flushing the DNS cache and nothing. What could've happened?

Comment: Similar questions at https://stackexchange.com/search?q=REMOTE+HOST+IDENTIFICATION+HAS+CHANGED, possibly some of them might address the question of why an Amazon host's identification might have changed

Comment: I tried deleting all known_hosts and it didn't work. It says "Permission denied (publickey)".

Comment: The only way is connecting to the public IP. Get access denied every time when using the amazon domain.

Answer (score 1):

You have a cached host key for that hostname in your ~/.ssh/known_hosts file.  Did you previously connect to a host with this same name, but then replace the instance?

Either remove your ~/.ssh/known_hosts file entirely, or remove the entry for the hostname from the file in an editor.

Comment: I tried this: "Deleted the known host and didn't work. ". The error after the first one is "Permission denied (publickey)."

Comment: The only way is connecting to the public IP. Get access denied every time when using the amazon domain.

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct hostname?  If the public IP has changed, the DNS will also change.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to remove the ssh keys belonging to a hostname or IP from your known hosts file.

```
ssh-keygen -R [hostname-or-IP]
```

Comment: You should always explain what a command does; I have done this for you this time, but you may wish to keep it in mind for future.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks Michael